# Explode Between Character PHP

Tags: php

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

// gets $url = http://www.facebook.com/UsedID

I want to explode url and get UserID only.

```
$userid = "UsedID";

echo "http://graph.facebook.com/$userid/picture ||";
```

I just Want to get The User Id.

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: "I have a teaspoon, and I need to hit a nail. Should I try hammering with my spoon or I should stick my head out and look for a better tool?"

Comment: Is it actually possible for the URL to end in other stuff like an anchor or added parameter? For example, the URL could be something like `http://www.facebook.com/UserID#someanchor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.facebook.com/UsedID";
$url = parse_url($url);
echo substr($url['path'], 1); //output: UsedID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = explode('/', $url);
$userId = array_pop($arr);
```

Comment: Nice and fast, but this will fail, if there's something appended to the URL (e.g. `http://www.facebook.com/UserID#someanchor` would return `UserID#someanchor`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = explode("/",$url);
$userid = $user[count($user)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$arr = explode("/", $url);
echo end($arr);
```

it will return the userid that is in the last of url.